# AZCOPY Login issue for copying files from Edge node to ADLS

Tags: azure, azcopy

I have a requirement where I have to move files from Edge node to ADLS. For this I am using the AZCOPY activity.

Here is my Code

```
export AZCOPY_AUTO_LOGIN_TYPE="SPN"
export AZCOPY_SPA_APPLICATION_ID="$client_id"
export AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET="$client_secret"
export AZCOPY_TENANT_ID="$tenant_id"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then   ////This always returns = 0. Though I pass correct or wrong credentials.
echo $?
echo "azure copy account login is successful"
else
echo "azure copy account login is failed"
exit
fi
```

I tried

```
az login --service-principal -u $clientid -p $client_secret --tenant myfyi.onmicrosoft.com
```

Note: I was given only Clientid, Client Secret, and Tenant id.

That doesn't work for me.
Can someone help me here.

Comment: What is not working? `az login` or `azcopy`? Also, the shell script you shared does nothing. It's just exporting something which would always give `exit 0`..

Comment: @harshavmb I am trying to perform az login and post that azcopy activity. but thats not happening with this code alone "az login --service-principal -u $clientid -p $client_secret --tenant myfyi.onmicrosoft.com"
This works only when I set up the ENV using 
export AZCOPY_AUTO_LOGIN_TYPE="SPN"
export AZCOPY_SPA_APPLICATION_ID="$client_id"
export AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET="$client_secret"
export AZCOPY_TENANT_ID="$tenant_id"
and followed by 
az login --service-principal -u $clientid -p $client_secret --tenant myfyi.onmicrosoft.com
only then it works.

Comment: Is there any other way by which we can achieve azlogin  using the above credentials. I tried all the possible ways suggested by azure Microsoft docs but they endup saying OAuth issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have  assigned the  Contributor role to your user account before performing operation so as to be authorized to your Azure Storage account.

For az login
try to create a service principal

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --role xxx
```

Then you can log in with the service principal with

```
az login --service-principal
```

or try also to create certificate and then login as shown here [azure cli - az login with certificate protected with password - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62477714/az-login-with-certificate-protected-with-password)

---

> If you set an environment variable by using the command line, that
> variable will be readable in your command line history

**Reference :[azcopy login | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-login)**

Please check this way

Log in as a service principal by using a client secret: Set the environment variable AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET to the client secret for secret based service principal auth.

```
azcopy login --service-principal --application-id <your service principal's application ID>
```

or

```
azcopy login --service-principal --application-id "$APP_ID" --tenant-id "$TENANT_ID"

if [[ $? -gt 0 ]]
then
    echo "azure copy account login failed"
else 
    echo "azure copy account login is successful"
fi
```

0 exit status means the command was successful without any errors. A non-zero  exit status means command was a failure.

**References:**

1. [azure - How to handle AZcopy failed file transfers - Stack
   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004873/how-to-handle-azcopy-failed-file-transfers)
2. [How to Copy All Containers along with Blobs from one Azure storage
   account to other storage account - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743848/how-to-copy-all-containers-along-with-blobs-from-one-azure-storage-account-to-ot/63512413#63512413)
3. [Use data transfer tools in Azure Stack Hub Storage - Azure Stack
   Hub | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-storage-transfer?view=azs-2108&tabs=az1)